# linux kernel version tag

Tags: tags, kernel, cross-compiling

I have an already built linux kernel image (zImage) and I want to generate the source for it.
However I'm facing trouble in that: I understand major/minor numbers meaning but I couldn't compile the same version:

```
target version: 4.5.0-00183-g4647b69-dirty
```

I even don't know the meaning of "00183-g4647b69-dirty" and how apply it.

thank in advance.
NB: I've copied the config.gz from the target kernel but in vain.
Both my own image and the other one are cross-compiled

Comment: Symbols after the first dash (`-`) are **distro-specific**, there is no generic meaning for them.

Comment: I've learned that this part is the UTS_RELEASE, but it's generated automatically. Is there any way to work around this and fix its value ?

Comment: What do you mean by "fix its value"? If you build kernel by hands, you may configure *any* [EXTRAVERSION](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336176/what-are-the-differences-of-editing-uts-release-and-extraversion) for it. The problem is to find **sources**, which have been used for original zImage you have. These sources are based on 4.5.0 version of vanilla kernel, but most probably have some modifications. Extraversion specifies which sources you should take. But again, meaning of extraversion is distro-specific.

Comment: I've figured that EXTRAVERSION is appended to the version number. The release name "00183-g4647b69-dirty" is autogenerated. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y. This option gets the kernel name from the "git describe" output.

In your version 4.5.0-00183-g4647b69-dirty,
"4.5.0" means the kernel version tag v4.5.0,
"00183" means you have 183 commits on top of v4.5.0
"g4647b69" means your HEAD commit SHA1 is 4647b69. (g is a prefix)
"-dirty" means you have local changes not committed to git.

What you probably need is CONFIG_LOCALVERSION=. You will be able to recreate your builds with this.